# Using Amazon S3 on django to upload Images with ImageField

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-models

I installed django-storages with pip (pip install django-storages)

got settings with AWS preferences:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bar.media'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MyAwesomeKeyId'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'BlahBlahBlah'
```

i got my model like this:

```
def Bar(Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bar')
```

on forms.py:

```
 class BarForm(forms.Form):
     image = forms.FileField(label='Logo',required=False)
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(BarForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.fields['image'].label='My Awesome Photo'
```

on views.py:

```
     @csrf_exempt
     def bar_web(request):
         context = {}
         if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BarForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            context['form'] = form
            if form.is_valid():
                    try:
                            logoFile = request.FILES['image']
                            print 'PIC: '+str(logoFile)
                    except:
                            logoFile = False 
                    if logoFile:
                          bar = Bar(image=logoFile)
                          bar.save()
                          bar.reload()
```

on the template:

```
         <p>Image Name: {{bar.image.name}}</p>
         <p>Image Url: {{bar.image.url}}</p>
         <p>Image : {{bar.image.content_type}}</p>
         <p>Image Path: {{bar.image.path}}</p>
```

But nothing printed.

I see currently the file name on prints; but nothing happen with s3. There is no file uploaded.

What's the error that I didn't see?

Comment: see this http://tartarus.org/james/diary/2013/07/18/fun-with-django-storage-backends it might help you.

Comment: Looks great; but didn't help. Same problem, i don't know what i make wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was a wrong configuration of IAM; these video may help to other users...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuffWMBeJkw